# MySQL statistics output

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I have a SQL file with temporary tables creation, some load data infile, some selects and some updates.

I would like to know the time spent on each statement, through the CLI on the shell. If my file contains:

```
SELECT "Step 1" AS '';
SELECT col1, col2 FROM t1 ORDER BY col3;
```

And I run:

```
mysql -h host db < file
```

The output I would like to get is:

```
Step 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
col1 col2
20073 0724081
20073 0724685
20073 0726347
20073 0726932
20073 0733623
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Tne `1 row in set (0.00 sec)` and `5 rows in set (0.00 sec)` are the information i'm looking for, **NOT** the Un*x time for the process.

I've tryied different `mysql` options, even `--show-warnings --i-am-a-dummy` to no avail. Is there a way to get the requested info?

Thanks,

**EDIT:** Added missing time for first select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try mysql profiler  - http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html

Comment: Thanks for the profiling info. I can use it for the time spent. Is there any way to get the number of returned rows?

Comment: @Danosaure - there is mysql_num_rows() and mysql_affected_rows() in C API, but you probably cannot access it via bash. Normally, I will do a `mysql -N -h host db < file| wc -l` or pipe the results into a file and do `wc -l`

Comment: Thanks for your tip but not applicable to my situation, as this SQL files have many statements and people can add more, but all the output should go into a single file. I cannot split into multiple files as it becomes unmanagable. These are "simple" tasks that I don't want to embed into program. The user will have to live with this output instead of knowing the exact numbers for each statement.  Also, I'm not sure about netiquette here, you have the most useful tip, but not the answer...

Comment: @Danosaure - In that case, you would need to explain it in the question. Anywhere, there is a function `found_rows()`, it can used together with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, details - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows . The drawback is you need to spit the query become two.

Comment: Sorry i though it was clear i wanted to have `5 rows in set (0.00 sec)` as specified in the OP. So combining `ROW_COUNT()` and `FOUND_ROWS()` gives me what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are losing the timing data due to rounding.   (eg, your query is taking A LOT less than 0.001 seconds.

Comment: The thing is.. I'm not getting that last line at all. I would like to have it for each line.